# Interactive image - React

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, image, svg

My users should be able to upload their college map to my app.

After that, he goes to an online editor in the app to select an image that matches one of the college maps they downloaded.

Once the edit mode is activated, they can click 4 times to apply the points A, B, C, D on the map.

These points indicate an area. This area will be indicated in the database and when the end users use the application, they will have access to the university map with this area as clickable. By clicking on it, they will have access to additional information.

I really don't know how to do it at all. I found some tracks with the SVG but I don't know how to relate the SVG to React and to the fact that the university can click 4 times (for points A, B, C, D) and this area becomes an SVG clickable thereafter.

Do you have any ideas to explore please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I understood correctly your problem.

If you want what image have 4 clickable area with different event onClick, you can set this image as background for ImageContainer, set for this container position: relative, and add children with position: absolute and onClick event

for each image you need have this data

```
    const image = {
      url: 'url',
      height: '1200px',
      width: '700px',
      clicableAreas: [
        {
          positionLeft: 50px,
          positionTop: 30px,
          width: 20px,
          height: 60px,
          onClick: () => doLogicAttachedToThisArea(),
        }
      ]
    }
```

this structure permitted add images with rectangular clickable area

```
function ImageContainer(image) {
  return <div style={{ 
    backgroundImage: image.url,
    width: image.width,
    height: image.height,
    position: 'relative',
}}>
      {image.clicableAreas.map(e => <div 
         onClick={data.onClick} 
         style={{
           left: e.positionLeft,
           top: e.positionTop,
           width: e.width,
           height: e.height,
         }}
       /> )}
  </div>
}
```